# Where condition is not working

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I have a SQL query. But that contains a where condition, and the OR in that where is not working.

Query

```
SELECT `st_student`.`st_id`, `ab_date`, `as_date` `st_status` 
FROM (`st_student`)
WHERE `st_status` =  1
OR `st_status` =  2
AND `ab_date` BETWEEN '08/01/2015' AND '08/31/2015'
OR `as_date` BETWEEN '08/01/2015' AND '08/31/2015'
AND `aca_no` =  2
GROUP BY `st_student`.`st_id`
```

This condition is not working:

```
OR `as_date` BETWEEN '08/01/2015' AND '08/31/2015'
```

Is there any mistake in that?

Comment: Store dates as dates.

Comment: You've accepted an answer which cannot possibly provide a meaningful result set. What are you actually trying to do? Proper CREATE and INSERTS statements (on a well-formed table with correct data types) and/or an sqlfiddle, TOGETHER with a desired result set might help to explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible error concerns the use of the `AND` and `OR` operators, since `AND` has priority over `OR`, and your query can be interpreted in the wrong way. So you should use the parentheses, and write something like this:

```
SELECT `st_student`.`st_id`, `ab_date`, `as_date` `st_status` 
FROM `st_student`
WHERE (`st_status` =  1 OR `st_status` =  2)
AND (`ab_date` BETWEEN '08/01/2015' AND '08/31/2015'
     OR `as_date` BETWEEN '08/01/2015' AND '08/31/2015')
AND `aca_no` =  2
GROUP BY `st_student`.`st_id`
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete

Comment: Am I right in thinking that if the dates are `varchar`, as the OP indicated, `BETWEEN` would treat the dates as strings and thus `08/31/2015` would come after `08/30/2016`?

Answer (score 0):

In case that your columns are declared as a varchar datatype you will need to use `str_to_date` function. Varchar cannot be compared as a date unless you convert it to one. Try this and let me know. Best of luck.

```
  SELECT `st_student`.`st_id`, `ab_date`, `as_date` `st_status` 
  FROM `st_student`
  WHERE (`st_status` =  1 OR `st_status` =  2)
  AND STR_TO_DATE(`ab_date`,'%d/%m/%Y')
  BETWEEN
  STR_TO_DATE('01/08/2015','%d/%m/%Y') 
  AND 
  STR_TO_DATE('31/08/2015','%d/%m/%Y')
  OR 
  STR_TO_DATE(`as_date`,'%d/%m/%Y')
  BETWEEN
  STR_TO_DATE('01/08/2015','%d/%m/%Y') 
  AND 
  STR_TO_DATE('31/08/2015','%d/%m/%Y')
  AND `aca_no` =  2
  GROUP BY `st_student`.`st_id`
```